# -bash: uname: command not found

Tags: bash, command-line

Getting an error in bash:

```
-bash: uname: command not found
```

I have checked the .bash_profile file and .bashrc file for their Paths and they seem to be correct. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Jesse_b redhat

Answer (score 1):

coreutils is usually what includes uname. Is the file in /bin?

```
$ls -l /bin/uname


-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35304 Aug 30 10:21 /bin/uname
```

If it's there check your environment.

```
$echo $PATH
```

Comment: its not in there, do I have to download it?

Comment: What distribution are you using? It's not typical to have it missing. It's possible it's located in a different directory on your distribution than mine.
Check also in /usr/bin and maybe even the /sbin or /usr/sbin
I've even seen it as a busybox tool on some distros....

Comment: It's definitely typical for OP to be missing coreutils if OP is using unix or another non-GNU distribution.

Comment: @dirtyredog redhat

Comment: @dirtyredog its in the /usr/bin directory, found it there

Comment: @dirtyredog  environment is correct as well